# How to configure PlantUML for JetBrains IDE on OS X Mavericks 10.9.1

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, rubymine, jetbrains-ide, plantuml

I used to use this plugin when I worked with Java EE in Eclipse.
It was very handy to write logic diagrams as a part of self documented code.

How can I use it with RubyMine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Install this plugin in RubyMine

- go to Preferences -> Plugins
- Click **Browse repositories** and search for **PlantUML**
- Select this plugin in the list to the right and choose **Download and Install** in the popup menu
- Restart IDE

2) In the command line install libtool and graphviz

> brew install libtool
>
> brew install graphviz

3) open some ruby file and add this code for a test 
(use block comment to isolate UML diagram from ruby translator  **=begin =end**)

```
=begin
@startuml
testdot
@enduml
=end
```

4) Go to menu **View -> Tool Windows -> PlantUML**

It should display

```
The environment variable GRAPHVIZ_DOT has not been set
Dot executable is /usr/local/bin/dot
Dot version: ...
Installation seems OK. File generation OK
```

Another example from official [website](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/usecase.html#Usecase)

```
=begin
@startuml
:First Actor:
  :Another actor: as Men2
actor Men3
actor :Last actor: as Men4
@enduml
=end
```